# I get Magento 2 (with Sample Data) installing error(s) and stopping process.. (in 67%)

Tags: magento2, php, database, wamp

```
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableSampleData': Installing data... [ERROR] Exception: Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away in H:\OSPanel\domains\magento\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 228 in H:\OSPanel\domains\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\ErrorHandler.php:61 
Stack trace: 
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'PDOStatement::e...', 'H:\\OSPanel\\doma...', 228, Array) 
#1 H:\OSPanel\domains\magento\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) 
#2 H:\OSPanel\domains\magento\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(93): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) 
#3 H:\OSPanel\domains\magento\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array) 
#4 H:\OSPanel\domains\magento\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) 
#5 H:\OSPanel\domains\magento\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `setup_m...', Array) 
#6 H:\OSPanel\domains\magento\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(517): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE `setup_m...', Array) 
#7 H:\OSPanel\domains\magento\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(580): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('UPDATE `setup_m...', Array) 
#8 H:\OSPanel\domains\magento\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(635): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('UPDATE `setup_m...', Array) 
#9 H:\OSPanel\domains\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Module\ModuleResource.php(131): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->update('setup_module', Array, '(module = 'Mage...') 
#10 H:\OSPanel\domains\magento\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(877): Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleResource->setDataVersion('Magento_Configu...', '2.0.0') 
#11 H:\OSPanel\domains\magento\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(791): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), 'data') 
#12 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures() 
#13 H:\OSPanel\domains\magento\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(342): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) 
#14 H:\OSPanel\domains\magento\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) 
#15 H:\OSPanel\domains\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() 
#16 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) 
#17 H:\OSPanel\domains\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) 
#18 H:\OSPanel\domains\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(214): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) 
#19 H:\OSPanel\domains\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) 
#20 H:\OSPanel\domains\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) 
#21 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) 
#22 H:\OSPanel\domains\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) 
#23 H:\OSPanel\domains\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(214): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) 
#24 H:\OSPanel\domains\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) 
#25 H:\OSPanel\domains\magento\setup\index.php(35): Zend\Mvc\Application->run() 
#26 {main}
```

Somethere, something need remove or maybe change. Any advices?

Answer (score 0):

your MySQL server seems not to be available (at least not to the install script). It's not possible to track down the reason only based on the stack trace you posted, but i would try the following:

- if mysql is running on a separate machine, see if you can reach it ("ping mysql-hostname.com")
- try to connect to mysql from your magento host ("mysql -h mysql-hostname.com -u username -p" - this will ask for a password)
- double-check your configuration, did you give the correct username/password?
- since the script seems to die halfway through the process: have a look at your mysql server configuration, or maybe try with a different mysql server

edit: also have a look at MySQLs "MySQL server has gone away" page, they list a few common reasons for that error: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html

for instance:

- missing privileges on the database / table
- dns resolve errors
- timeout on behalf of the database
- ...

Comment: Yes, I tried last easier or not difficult in my case way. I changed my used WAMP to different (to XAMPP local server. It has simple menu and correct default configurations). And problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Magento2 using below command:

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://127.0.0.1/mage2_sample" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="mage2_sample" --db-user="root" --db-password="root" --admin-firstname="Charvi" --admin-lastname="Parikh" --admin-email="test@gmail.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin"
```

**Note:** Please set base-url, admin-details,db details etc as per your requirement. After running this command successfully, Magento 2 will be installed with sample data.